# Is there a folk theorem for repeated games on networks?

Tags: game-theory, reference-request, networks

Games on networks have been studied extensively, however, I was not able to find a [folk theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folk_theorem_%28game_theory%29) for games on networks. Is there one or can it be derived from an already existing folk theorem?

With **games on networks** I mean games in which the payoff of the stage game only depends on the actions of the direct neighbors in a network. Simple examples for that would be the the majority game (in which the payoff depends on the number of neighbors that play the same action as you are) or a prisoner's dilemma played with each neighbor.

Comment: I won't post it as an answer because I haven't read the paper, but it looks like this could be what you are after: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0899825612001285. It's in GEB, so it should be pretty decent.

Comment: @Ubiquitous Thanks! It wasn't really exactly what I was thinking about (as it includes communication and incomplete information about the actions), but it would be a good answer non the less. In addition there are some references in there that look like they could be what I am looking for.

Comment: In this stage its critical to get answers, so it would be better if you posted it as such.

Comment: @Ubiquitous your comment lead to an answer, do you want to make an answer out of it? Otherwise I will write one as soon as I have the time.

Comment: @TheAlmightyBob Now might be a good time to make it into an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there are folk theorems for games on networks, depending on information structure and possible communication. Here are some of the most relevant papers:

- Ben-Porath, E., & Kahneman, M. (1996). [Communication in repeated
  games with private monitoring](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022053196900903). Journal of Economic Theory, 70(2),
  281-297. - *public communication, private monitoring*
- Renault, J., & Tomala, T. (1998). [Repeated proximity games](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s001820050089).
  International Journal of Game Theory, 27(4), 539-559. - *complete information, imperfect monitoring*
- Tomala, T. (2011). [Fault reporting in partially known networks and
  folk theorems](http://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/opre.1110.0936). Operations research, 59(3), 754-763. - *partial knowledge of the network and restricted communication*
- Laclau, M. (2012). [A folk theorem for repeated games played on a
  network](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0899825612001285). Games and Economic Behavior, 76(2), 711-737. - *private communication*

Thanks @Ubiquitous for basically providing the answer.